# Getting real-time market/stock quotes in C#/Java

Tags: c#, java, stocks

I would like to make an program that acts like a big filter for stocks. To do so, I need to have real-time (or delayed) quotes from the market. I started getting stock quotes by requesting pages from yahoo, accordingand parsing the html to the ticker, and parsing the html. I was wondering how to do this requesting and parsing html. Is there some way I can request only the stock quotes and its info? I know some applications do this, and I am very curious how they do it, because requesting web pages and parsing them is very time-consuming.

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: I am doing something similar including option prices. I know you can get pay access, but a web service with pricing would be priceless if free. :)

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but this may help you anyway: Since you're building a "filter" for stocks, you may need company fundamental information (revenue, profit, number of employees, industry codes, etc) - a great place to get all of that is the Mergent Fundamentals API - http://www.mergent.com/servius/

Comment: For a ready made solution check the following link codecanyon.net/item/livecurrent-stock-price-/17489243 . DLL and sample code file provided,very easy to integrate in web as well as desktop applications.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Parsing the output of the webpage is a chump's game. It is always changing and unless you're willing to heavily invest in some sort of very resilient parser you're going to spend your life twiddling with it.  Use a web service, google offers one http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2007/01/real-time-quotes-for-free.html

Comment: Yahoo offers there data for free check out http://jarloo.com/tutorials/get-yahoo-finance-api-data-via-yql/  to learn YQL and how to download Yahoo Finance data.

Comment: what you say is true, I just wanted to add that if you are forced to do html parsing, using jsoup and xpath will make that task a lot easier.  Sometimes the data you need just isn't available any other way.

Comment: This Google page seems to have nothing but an empty promise. Where is the Web service?

Comment: For a ready made solution check the following link http://codecanyon.net/item/livecurrent-stock-price-/17489243 . DLL and sample code file provided,very easy to integrate in web as well as desktop applications.

Comment: @Kelly Yahoo has just discontinued the service.

Answer (score 10):

You can get csv data from yahoo.

[This page](http://www.gummy-stuff.org/Yahoo-data.htm) has more information.

Comment: This page has been removed because of infringement on Yahoo Terms of Service

Answer (score 4):

The Google and Yahoo API's have both gone away.  However, [Investor's Exchange offers an API](https://iextrading.com/developer/docs/) that's very easy to use for quote data.

Comment: Can I use this to fetch quotes of NSE listed stocks as well?

Comment: IEX supports a number of different exchanges; there is an API to fetch the full list.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik, this kind of data is available via subscription based models, [Xignite](http://www.xignite.com/product/global-real-time-stock-quote-data/) is one that comes to mind. To my knowledge, NASDAQ and the NYSE do not provide any freely usable API's.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually a yahoo web service that will return CSV file of stock quotes. So no HTML parsing needed

Comment: Discontinued service now

Answer (score 1):

In the financial services industry, most banks will have a real time feed provided by Reuters or Bloomberg, but this, obviously, will cost a lot of money.  If you Google for "stock price feed" or "market data feed" you will get some options, some free, some paid for.

I would also recommend using a Complex Event Processing engine such as [Esper](http://esper.codehaus.org/) for doing this sort of real time processing, it will be substantially easier than writing the whole application stack from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

For downloading yahoo finance stock quotes in C# or VB.NET you can use the "Yahoo! Finance Managed" library.

[Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/YahooFinance_Managed.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

this internally uses yahoo stock api.
i hope this one helps you out.

https://github.com/bhattumang7/gold-silver-share-price-api-india

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at this [channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/pdc2008/TL11/) presentation. It is a F# introduction but from 27:00 the presenter, Luca Bolognesi, creates an application that does some of the work you are asking for (in F# but very inspirational - to me at least).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [list of websites](http://www.quantshare.com/sa-426-6-ways-to-download-free-intraday-and-tick-data-for-the-us-stock-market) that provide free intraday data.

You can export the data and use it in your software

Answer (score 0):

Using Fidelity.com & inspecting the element for the selling price you can manipulate the URL to search any stock from inside your program.

Using Visual Studio Community 2013 C#